# Can't seem to get autocomplete to work in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I'm having trouble getting autocomplete of basic attributes and methods working in Node.js for WebStorm. This is what it looks like:

[image: Bad functionality in WebStorm]

This is what it should look like: (VSCode)

[image: Correct functionality on VSCode]

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's fixed in 2019.1:

[image]

You can try downloading the EAP from https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367229-WebStorm?sort_by=recent_activity